# Find all values of z for which $z^6 = (z+1)^6$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $\frac{z^6}{(z+1)^6} = 1 = e^{2k\pi i}$.

Comment: Hint : Do the division in the other sense.

Answer (score 0):

If $z^6 = (z+1)^6$, then $e^{2k\pi i/6}z = z+1$ for some $k = 0, ..., 5$. This gives you 6 linear equations, one for each $k$, and you can solve them individually to get your solutions.